# How can we solve it for the value of current Ia?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

By solving loop 4 using KVL,
 I4= -0.5Ia = -0.5(I4-I3)
 how?

Comment: As you said, by solving. Show some attempts, and then we can help you with that approach!

Comment: What's flowing through the 1 ohm resistor?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a homework question with zero attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no contradiction in this:

$$I_4 = -0.5(I_4 - I_3)$$
$$1.5 I_4 = 0.5 I_3$$
$$I_4 = \frac{0.5}{1.5}I_3$$

When you add the equations for meshes 1, 2, and 3, you'll be able to get the solution in terms of \$V_1\$.